# libfreenect2 example Protonect only showing raw feed?

Tags: linux, opencl, kinect, openkinect, pocl

I figure the Protonect example in libfreenect2 is supposed to show more than just this raw feed?

[image]

I am running Linux Mint 17.2 and pocl 0.11 for OpenCL on an i7 4790.
The system has llvm-3.6 installed.
This is the output of clinfo.

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
  Platform Vendor                                 The pocl project
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 pocl 0.11
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             POCL

  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  Device Vendor                                   pocl
  Device Vendor ID                                0x0
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 pocl
  Driver Version                                  0.11
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2
  Device Type                                     CPU, Default
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               8
  Max clock frequency                             4000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     2
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             18446744073709551615x18446744073709551615x18446744073709551615
  Max work group size                             4096
  Preferred work group size multiple              8
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 8 / 8        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              33643532288 (31.33GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           8410883072 (7.833GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       128 bits (16 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
pocl warning: encountered incomplete implementation in clGetDeviceInfo.c:135
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            0 pixels
pocl warning: encountered incomplete implementation in clGetDeviceInfo.c:137
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 0 images
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               8410883072 (7.833GiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        8410883072 (7.833GiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      0ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
pocl warning: encountered incomplete implementation in clGetDeviceInfo.c:257
  printf() buffer size                            0
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Portable Computing Language
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [POCL]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [POCL]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Portable Computing Language
    Device Name                                   pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.1.3
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 1.2
```

Any thoughts as to what could be wrong? This is my first time using OpenCL on a CPU instead of a GPU and also my first time trying anything with a Kinect so I am not very familiar. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OpenCL` doesn't matter, because you're not using `OpenCL`. In the output you can see `OpenGLDepthPacketProcessor`, which is the default in protonect. I think there has been some trouble with that on Linux recently. Try starting protonect with the `cl` command line parameter:

```
./protonect cl
```

That should make sure the `OpenCL` implementation is used.

You can also try the `cpu` parameter instead, using neither `OpenGL` nor `OpenCL`. That will be way slower, but should at least work without worrying about the correct `OpenGL`/`OpenCL` drivers.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to run with the `cpu` parameter. I guess I'll just have to see what I can do about updating the Mesa drivers, and also see if I can take advantage of OpenCL.